How to pass an object into a class that references other objects to change their values
I am making an idle game library for my use and I am unsure how to go about creating a system that takes pairs of resources and amounts, checks if they are available, and if so then adjust all the values. Accessing the said resources and putting them in an object to pass into Building() is quite hard.
What I need to do is get the resources in player.resources from a method inside an object in player.building a long with amounts of each resource.
I want to pass all of this information into a new class Building() object like this:
// Inside player.buildings
purple: new Building(0, "#purple", /*data goes here*/)

class Building extends Thing(){
    constructor(amount, tag, requirements){
        super(amount, tag)
        this.requirements = requirements
        /*
        This is roughly the shape of the input. It is the reference to the resources and the respective amounts needed.
        requirements = {
            player.resources.red: 5,
            player.resources.blue: 92,
        }
        */
    }

    buy(){
        // Check if each of the required resources are avaliable
        for(let resource of this.requirements){
            if(resource.amount >= resource.needed){
                continue
            }else{
                //Break the loop and return false, signaling that you cant buy this right now.
                return false
            }
        }
        // If you can buy it then go through each of the required resources and decrement them.
        for(let resource of this.requirements){
             resource.amount -= resource.needed
        }
        this.amount += 1
    }
}

For context a Thing or Resource has this structure:
resource:{
   amount: x,
   tag: "#tag", //Used for rendering on the page
}

The player object has this structure
player:{
   resources:{
      red: {
         amount: 3,
         tag: "#red"
   },
      blue: {
        amount: 4,
        tag: "#blue"
   },
   buildings:{
      purple: {
         amount: 0,
         tag: "#purple",
         requirements: "data structure",
      }
   },
}


What exactly is the issue?

I want to input a data structure into a new Building object that specifies what resources and how many are needed. All of these are contained in a Player object.

Are you asking how do you specify a price (in resources) for a type of building?  Or are you asking how to get a player to buy a building?

I want to specify the price in resources to buy this type of building. The buy() method is what is executed when the building is bought.

requirements: (blue: 1, red: 1} or requirements: [{type: "blue", amount: 1},{type: "red", amount: 1}] depending on your preference/constraints.

How do I reference the blue and red resource objects to access their amounts?

You return from the buy() function as soon as you encounter a resource whose amount is less than resourceNeeded.

Shouldn't requirements be this.requirements?

It's not clear why you need both for loops. Just the second should be enough. It skips updating the resources whose amount is too low. If you need to know if any were found, set a flag variable.

@barmar
The idea is to check each amount that is required. If you don't have enough of a resource, then return false immediately. If only one of the resources doesn't have enough, it would be wasteful to calculate all the others.
The code in buy() Is a rough estimate of what I want the code to do.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can pass in the player object when you call the buy function.  Then using your previous logic, you can check that the player has enough resources and then deduct them.  Here I also added the building to the player's "buildings" object as an example.


class Thing {
  constructor(amount, tag){
    this.amount = amount;
    this.tag = tag;
  }
}

class Building extends Thing {
    constructor(amount, tag, requirements){
        super(amount, tag)
        this.requirements = requirements;
    }

    buy(player){
        // Check if each of the required resources are avaliable
        for (let [type, amount] of Object.entries(this.requirements)) {
            if(player.resources[type].amount >= amount){
                continue
            }else{
                return false
            }
        }
        // If you can buy it then go through each of the required resources and decrement them.
        for (let [type, amount] of Object.entries(this.requirements)) {
          player.resources[type].amount -= amount;
        }
        this.amount += 1;
        // do something with this building (add it to the player's "buildings" property, for example)
        player.buildings[this.tag] = this;
        
        return true;
    }
}

const logCabin = new Building(0, "log cabin", {red: 1, blue: 1});

const player1 = {
   resources:{
      red: {
         amount: 3,
         tag: "#red"
      },
      blue: {
        amount: 4,
        tag: "#blue"
      }
   },
   buildings:{}
};

let result = logCabin.buy(player1);
console.log(result);
console.log(player1);




Is there a way to create the Building() inside the player object?

I want to be able to package the player object and save it using cookies or other processes.

Doing things with cookies is a different can of worms.  Note that class instances do not survive transformation via json.stringify / json.parse, so it's unlikely you'd want instances of Building in the player object at all if that is your intention.
